# Why does the "shading" tab sometimes make my model to disappear?

Tags: shaders

Very much a newbie here. I created my model, a carrot, and I would like to do some colour on it. So I click on the "shading" tap and then the whole model disappears!

I thought it was a scaling issue (and it looks like my model is down there) but no matter how much I zoom in, I never get to the model. When I leave shading, the model shows up again.

Please help :(

Comment: Hi. Please add some images to your question to illustrate what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: The shading viewport has an independent "view camera" to the main layout viewport. If "no amount of zooming" will get to your object, this likely means you have hit the zoom threshold (zoomed in all the way), and cant go any farther by zooming. Try to pan to your object using shift and the middle mouse button the same as in the main viewport.